# How to convert a column of x years and y months into [12(x)+y] months

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

My data has a remaining_lease column where it is in x years and y months
I would like to change it into [12(x)+y] months
[image: Here is a picture of the data]

I have tried the code below but an error keeps occuring

```py
import pandas as pd

def lease_string_to_months(time):
    split_string = time.split(' ')
    months = 12*int(split_string[0]) + int(split_string[2])
    return months

df1 = 'resale-flat-prices-based-on-registration-date-from-jan-2017-onwards.csv' # write the filepath here as a string
house_lease = pd.read_csv(df1)
new_header = house_lease.iloc[0]
house_lease = house_lease[1:]
house_lease.columns = new_header
house_lease['remaining_lease'].map(lease_string_to_months)
```

Comment: what is the purpose of modifying the columns? If you need to drop column - just drop it with ``house_lease.drop(['not_needed_column'], axis=1)``. Also I feel you don't understand what ``read_csv()`` returns. Please read first or at least print out ``house_lease``.

Comment: I need to use the column for comparison with the resale price. The previous code was a mistake thanks for pointing it out. Any idea how to convert the years and months into just years?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First - read about [`pd.read_csv()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) as well as inspect what you have in `house_lease`. In other words, I doubt that you need most of your transformations.

Since I don't have your cvs file, I made toy example here, split `remaining_lease` (string) column, converted [0]th & 2th columns to number,  pushed 12*Y+M to a new `months` column in dataframe.

```py
import pandas as pd
d = {'remaining_lease': ['55 years 12 months', '12 years 01 months']}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
rdf = df['remaining_lease'] \
    .str.split(r" ", expand=True) \
    .iloc[:, [0,2]] \
    .apply(pd.to_numeric)
df['months'] = 12*rdf[0] + rdf[2]

print(df)

>     remaining_lease  months
0  55 years 12 months     672
1  12 years 01 months     145
```